# Out of Memory Exception When loading report into a Datagrid in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, out-of-memory

Showing Out of Memory Exception When loading  report  into a Datagrid  in VB.net web application.
It is working fine with 2000+ rows data..When no of rows is higher(5000+) it showing out of memory exception.no images loading in to the grid only text values
.Still showing out of  memory exception.
How to solve this

here is my code
`

```
          If objTable.Rows.Count < 15000 Then
            grdList.DataSource = objTable
            grdList.DataBind()


            For i = 0 To grdList.Items.Count - 1
                If grdList.Items(i).Cells(0).Text = "N" Then
                    grdList.Items(i).Cells(0).Text = ""
                    grdList.Items(i).Cells(1).ColumnSpan = o
                   
                    For j = 2 To o
                        grdList.Items(i).Cells(j).Visible = False
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If`



 <asp:DataGrid ID="grdList" runat="server" >
                            </asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do you really think that someone can solve this with that amount of information?

Comment: @mary Sorry ..updated the question

Comment: DataGrid is available in the WPF toolbox. In a web application we have GridView. In WinForms DataGridView. Are you loading a GridView? All the names are similar.

Comment: <asp:DataGrid ID="grdList" runat="server" >
                                </asp:DataGrid>

Comment: @mary its Datagrid only.

Comment: You should be using paging for that much data.